# making a makefile for a template class

Tags: c++, templates, makefile

So I have couple of files that I want to compile together. One of them is stack.h with stack.cpp included.

The following is my header file:

```
#include<iostream>
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H 
template <class ItemType>
class StackType
{
public:
    //code

private:
    //code   
};
#include "stack.cpp"
#endif
```

The following is stack.cpp:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
StackType<ItemType>::StackType(){
    top = -1;
    MAX_ITEMS = 200;
}

//other codes
}
```

When I make it says that I am redefining the code in stack.cpp

The following is my Makefile:

```
main.o: main.cpp stack.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.cpp
stack.o: stack.cpp stack.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o stack.o stack.cpp
```

I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: What says you are redefining code? Please post the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not attempt to compile a `stack.o`. This is template code that needs to be included in the client code and cannot be built. Just add the `stack.cpp` dependency to the `main.o` rule (assuming main.cpp includes `stack.h`, and remove the `stack.o` rule:

```
main.o: main.cpp stack.h stack.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

You have a further problem, and that is that you include `stack.h` in `stack.cpp`, and vice versa. You should remove the `#include stack.h` from `stack.cpp`.

Since template code should not be compiled by itself, I suggest changing the suffix of `stack.cpp` to something else, such as `.icpp`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of separating your interface and implementation, even for templates, is a respectable position to take.  Might I suggest though that you do not call template implementation files .cpp files.  Boost uses ipp for this case, it seems reasonable to me.

You did the right thing in including it, just the wrong thing in compiling it...which the .cpp would indicate you should do.